# Abstract Algebra Elementary Properties of Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, abelian-groups

This is Excercise 4.A.5 from Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra":

Let $a$, and $x$ be elements of a group $G$. Solve for $x$ in terms of $a$.

Solve Simultaneously:

$x^2 = a^2$ and $x^5 = e$

---

Okay, so here is my thought on solving it. I want to get $(x^2 = a^2)$ in the form of $(x^5)$ so as to substitute from the second equation.

Process:

$x^2 = a^2$
$(x)(x)(x)(x^2)=(x)(x)(x)a^2$
$x^5 = (x^3)(a^2)$

then substitute from the second equation gives:

$e = (x^3)(a^2)$

Now I want to get $x$ to one side of the equation and all of the $a$'s to another, so:

$e(a^{-1})=(x^3)(a)(a)(a^{-1})$
$e(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=(x^3)(a)(a^{-1})$
$e(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=x^3$
$(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=x^3$

This is where I can get the equation pretty confidently, from here though I want to reduce it even further. My idea is to substitute out two of the $x$'s on the right hand side and substitute in $a$^2. I can't think of a logical reason that I shouldn't be able to do this, but I have this gut feeling that I don't want to use this because I am already manipulating this equation. (Idk, maybe its a left over feeling from linear algebra or something?)

Anyhow, is this correct?:

$(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=(x)(x^2)$
$(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=x(a^2)$
$(a^{-1})(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=x(a)(a)(a^{-1})$
$(a^{-1})(a^{-1})(a^{-1})(a^{-1})=x(a)(a^{-1})$
$(a^{-1})^4 = x$

Is that valid?

Comment: We strongly encourage that you format your questions and work in progress.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have you posted the full question exactly as it is stated in the book?

Comment: I have a feeling that you've overlooked some of the example problems that were solved for you in the section where this set of exercises was given.  In any case there doesn't seem to be enough information to guarantee a unique solution.  For example, if $a^5 = e$, then $x=a$ would be one solution, but if $a^5\neq e$, then is would not be a solution.

Comment: But why do you start out mentioning $b$ and $c$?  Those don't seem to come up later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x = x e =x x^5 = x^6 = (x^2)^3 = (a^2)^3 = a^6$

But you are right that $x=a^{-4}$ also, because $x^2=a^2$ implies $e=x^{10}=a^{10}=a^4 a^6$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the truth is that there are no $b,c~$'s in the exercise. So, if there is a solution $x$, then it has to be $a$, since:

$x=x^5(x^2)^{-2}=e(a^2)^{-2}=a^{-4}.$

On the other hand, notice that there is no guarantee that your "system" is solved in terms of $x$, i.e. we don't know that there is a asolution at all (therefore more information is needed). (Edit. The same remark as @hardmath did).